# How do I speed up scrolling in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, speed, scrolling

When I scroll a list for example in [Total Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander)'s *Synchronize Dirs*, or in a text file with its Lister, scrolling is very slow, if I do multiple scrolls at once.

The problem is that if the lines I want to skip are many, I do many scrolls on the wheel. I expect it to scroll much more at once! But Windows handles this really differently, and if you ask me in a buggy way, because multiple scroll *slows it down more than if I would have done separate scrolls* (or at least it feels like it). In particular the actual looks feel buggy, too.

I've tried to set the scroll speed according to this:
*[Change mouse settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14206/windows-7-change-mouse-settings)* basically says:

*Control Panel* → *Mouse* → *Wheel tab*; set your stuff.

I've set it to screen and later to 10 and noticed that the scrolling is still slow. I suspect it's the animation.

Comment: Some video cards stay stepped down in 2D modes, reserving thier real speed for 3D. If you had some really poorly programmed 2D displaying going on you could test by stepping up your grafics card (not referring to overclocking), and see if that helps. I use rather odd methods, so I could not tell you how to do it on yours.

Comment: @Psycogeek I have `Intel HD Graphics Family`, hw id: `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0102&SUBSYS_1494103C&REV_09`, `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0102&CC_030000`, driver version `8.15.10.2509`.

Comment: Have you tried middle-click-dragging?  I've had better luck with some programs by doing that.

Comment: @RossAiken Thanks good suggestion, I've actually used to do middle click + drag, if it's that what you mean. (It's dependent on the mouse driver however, on some hardware it didn't appear.) It's the opposite, it's too fast for me sometimes and hard to control due to the speed. But yes I used that as workaround before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the animation, and another question has an answer: *[Windows Forms: How do I disable `ListView` scroll animation (smooth-scrolling)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457851/windows-forms-how-do-i-disable-listview-scroll-animation-smooth-scrolling/8457960#8457960)*

It basically says,

Go to: *Control panel* → *System* → *Advanced system settings* (to the left on the side) → *"Advanced"* tab → *Performance* → *Settings* → *Visual Effects Tab*

**Remove** the checkbox from:

- *Animate controls and elements inside windows* and
- from *smooth-scroll list boxes*.

I tried this and the scrolling is now **fast**!

Combined with *Control Panel* → *Mouse* → *Wheel tab*, it solves my problem.

Comment: I lack explicitly setting the scroll-smoothing speed though. Maybe a much-much faster smooth would be better, maybe it wouldn't make difference, but it would be nice if I could set it.